# How do you compare 2 players in different leagues in SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Using sc2ranks.com we can see the points accumulated by each player.

Are the points of a player comparable to players in other leagues?

If not, why not and what happens to a players points upon demotion/promotion?

Is there a better way to compare players ( other than just playing each other )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive played through a couple promotions and it seems like points are maintained across promotions.

I know this wasn't always true, but it was on nov 17 (last promotion I had).

That said there is no good way to compare players who haven't faced off... Period.

Not across leagues, not across divisions, not within divisions. Points are a completely inaccurate measurement and rankings are based off of points. If we look at the blizzard top 200 (released) we see poor correlation with points. Blizzard uses hidden ranking for those numbers. If we compare that ranking to the [ELO ranking](http://www.teamliquid.net/tlpd/sc2-korean/players) that some fan sites use, we see an even different set of results.

The reality is that voting systems (game theory) require impractical amounts of data for a game like starcraft. The result being that you rarely ever get an accurate ranking system.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Care to link to where you can see ELO rankings?

Comment: @tzenes ...The top 200 is based solely off of points after applying the division modifiers. Also, I am fairly confident you lose some of your points upon being promoted, although I could not tell you how many.

Comment: @en1gmatic I thought the same, but I did not lose any points on my last 3 promotions so I'm starting to doubt that.  As to the top 200.  I have heard a lot of talk about "division modifiers" but I have yet to see hard evidence to back that up.  Usually the modifiers used are very large numbers that provide a nice "fit" to the 200 data points, but aren't able to accurately predict successive lists.

Comment: @Troynt added..

Comment: @tzenes No inconsistencies for division tiers have been found as far as I know: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=169830

Comment: @En1gmatic you'll notice he updates those numbers over time to be consistent with each new week.  This is reverse engineering the algorithm blizzard uses through regression analysis.  Such an approach is susceptible to creating an algorithm that "fits" the data without being accurate.

Comment: @tzenes The 63 point modifier per tier has remained the same since that thread was started. Also, it is based off of information given by blizzard employees at blizzcon. 
'We know that divisions are not equal, confirmed at Blizzcon.
We know that the Top 200 is generated by points without factoring in "the skill of your division."
We know that the Top 200 is not based on MMR or any other factor except points (including bonus used), confirmed at Blizzcon.'

Comment: @en1gmatic I was actually at blizzcon and that was definitely the implication of what was said, but it is not an accurate quote. The wording used was: we consider it [the visible points]. Regardless I think were quibbling here. If you want to beleive there is a correlation between two inaccurate systems: feel free; they are inaccurate regardless. I'm going too wait till there is solid evidence before making a bold assertion like that